# Not getting into initramfs shell on pi400

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I try to get into the initramfs shell on my pi400 but hdmi-monitor always keeps black after showing some boot messages. Any ideas?

My config.txt:

```
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
arm_64bit=1
disable_overscan=1
[cm4]
otg_mode=1
[all]
[pi4]
arm_boost=1
[all]
initramfs initramfs.gz followkernel
```

Why I am doing that? I am following to one of the many almost identical tutorials [1] for full encryption of my sd-card with LUKS but without success.

1. p. ex.  https://rr-developer.github.io/LUKS-on-Raspberry-Pi/

Answer (score 0):

Not to enable DRM VC4 V3D driver was the solution. So I comment those lines in *config.txt*:

```
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
#max_framebuffers=2
```